# Connecting to shards separately to read only, speed performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, pymongo

Problem.  I need to read documents from Mongodb, 500M documents, it is sharded to 10 shards.

My biggest issue is the speed, right now.

I have connected to each shard separately and read each one as separate task, assuming my speed will increase 10x.

It is somewhat faster, but still not fast enough.

Any suggestions to increase the speed?

Note: I am reading document by document from the cursor. 
Trying not have lower memory footprint.
Right now, it takes

26 sec to go over 100K documents, on 1 shard
4.5 min to go over 1M documents, on 10 shards

So from here, it looks like it will take 37.5 hrs to go over 500M.

Anyone have dealt with speed optimization issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips to improve the speed with some assumptions

1. MongoDB is a nosql database which uses quorum for consistency and reliability. In your case though you are reading from  shards separately but MongoDB uses quorum of 3 by default. (it means reads will be happen from 3 replicas and then most newest/consistent results are served). Here I am assuming your environment is replicated with a factor of 3
   Making quorum value 1 will provide results faster but might be inconsistent/old.
2. Indexing is commonly used option in all databases to read records (and only required fields) much faster than normal reads.
3. Use of SSDs instead of rotating disks will give you better throughput (Though might not be applicable in current case but should be helpful in future)
4. MongoDB 3.0 version uses WiredTiger Engine which claimed to be much faster (5x-7x) than older version.

Another option you can consider if you have more money, is adding more shards in the system and scale it horizontally

Before jumping to optimize read latency, Why do you need to read all 500M records in the DB? 
Reading all records from database makes no sense in normal real life oltp transactions.

Comment: Thanks! 3. I have a test enviroment, and dev is on AWS. 4. Mongo 3.2.9.  
I am reading the data to do analytical work on it, and it is not performing well speed wise. I was looking for the ways to optimize it.  Thanks anyway. I need to find a solution using pymongo.